# source/lib not available in magento 2 frontend design

Tags: magento2, design, magento-2.0

trying to modify magento theme blank / luma i realized that code with name -> app/design/frontend/magento/theme/web/css/source/lib is not available in the application, but referred many times in other files mainly .less code.

an example is less code contained in: app\design\frontend\Magento\blank\web\css\styles-l.less

in line 30 displays:

```
@import 'source/lib/_responsive.less';
```

but no folder /lib or file _responsive.less is available.

any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find this in folder magento-root/lib/web/css/source/lib/_responsive.less

Thank you

Comment: thanks, any idea why the theme luma requested inside its code and not in LIB?

Comment: No such Idea as I have just started Magento 2. But will get back as soon as I find anything. Basically, this has been done because the structure of responsive has to be same all across all the themes.